XL-Deploy Parent and Child CI
In my daily work I develop XL-Deploy plugins. Not the official ones of xebialabs though. In the synthetic.xml file of our plugins, we use very often a Parent CI - Child CI "architecture". Since we create types that extend from very different CIs, I would like to know what connects the Parent with the Child. Is it the "reference" in the synthetic.xml file?
I did not attempt any experiments of removing parts of the synthetic file to find an answer for this, but I will do that as an attempt to find out the answer.

The parent-child connection is set with the referenced-type and as-containment attributes.  This property makes the current object a child of an overthere.Host object:
<property name="host" kind="ci" referenced-type="overthere.Host" as-containment="true" />

